# Update TableA with different column values of TableC, which columns values need to be used is configured in TableB

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update, dynamic-sql

Table Structure

```
TableA
+---------+--------+--------+
| ColA1   | ColA2  |  ColA3 |
+---------+--------+--------+
|  1      |  B1    |        |
+---------+--------+--------+
|  2      |  B2    |        |
+---------+--------+--------+

TableB
+---------+--------+--------+
| ColB1   | ColB2  |  ColB3 |
+---------+--------+--------+
|  1      |  B1    |  ColC2 |
+---------+--------+--------+
|  2      |  B2    |  ColC3 |
+---------+--------+--------+


TableC
+---------+--------+--------+
| ColC1   | ColC2  |  ColC3 |
+---------+--------+--------+
|  1      |  100   |  1000  |
+---------+--------+--------+
|  2      |  200   |  2000  |
+---------+--------+--------+
```

Here, the column ColA3(TableA) needs to be updated with different column values from TableC based on ColA1 = ColC1. ColA3 may have value from ColC2 or ColC3 (which columns need to be used are configured in ColB3(TableB)).

For row with 1(ColA1), the ColA3 will be 100, and for row with 2(ColA1), the ColA3 will be 2000

As the TableC column names are specified as ColB3 column values I tried dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Query = N'UPDATE TableA SET ColA3 = (SELECT '+ tabB.ColB3 +' FROM TableC WHERE ColC1 = tabA.ColA1) FROM TableA tabA JOIN TableB tabB ON tabA.ColA2 = tabB.ColB2';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

But don't know how to get TableC column name instead of "tabB.ColB3". Please advice me on the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE  a 
SET ColA3 = CASE WHEN b.colb3 = 'ColC2' THEN c.ColC2 WHEN b.colb3 ='ColC3' THEN c.ColC3 END
FROM       tablea a 
INNER JOIN tableb b ON a.ColA2 = b.ColB2 
INNER JOIN tablec c ON a.cola1 = c.colc1

Comment: Thanks but there are 7 types and in future it may increase. That's why looking for a generic option.